# loop through pandas dataframe to delete duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

eg I have following df:

```
**names**           **score**       WhatIWant
Jones, Tom, Eddy       119.        Jones, Tom, Eddy
Nick, Tim, Bob         222.        Nick, Tim, Bob
Jones, Eddy, Luke      221.            Luke
Timmy, Jones, Sam        112.      Timmy, Sam
```

I need to loop through this dataframe and delete all duplicate names in column 'names', i.e. remove those names which have appeared in earlier rows.

For example in row 1 and row 3 Jones and Eddy is repeated, I want them to be removed from row 3.

Comment: what should your required output look like? -- from your example, none of the rows are duplicate, neither are any of the `names` in a single row

Comment: you can see that for example in row 1 and in row 3, name Jones is repeated, so i need to delete it duplicate, so i would only remain with one name Jones

Comment: which one would you retain? add a similar table with you required output. It's just easy to understand when you have a have and a want data. check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['names'] = ['Jones, Tom, Eddy', 'Nick, Tim, Bob', 'Jones, Eddy, Luke', 'Timmy, Jones, Sam']
df['scores'] = [119, 222, 221, 112]

names_till_now = []
def get_unique_names(names_till_now, names_string):
    names_list = names_string.split(",")
    names_list = [name.strip() for name in names_list]
    names_unique = [i for i in names_list if i not in names_till_now]
    names_till_now += names_list
    return ', '.join(name for name in names_unique)

df['names'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_unique_names(names_till_now, x['names']),axis=1)
df
```

And the output is as follows

```
    names                     scores
0   Jones, Tom, Eddy          119
1   Nick, Tim, Bob            222
2   Luke                      221
3   Timmy, Sam                112
```

Comment: i've tried it, doesnt work for me. I have edited my question, maybe first time I interpreted it wrong

Comment: Edited my answer according to the edited question, check if this works

Comment: a minor suggestion - apply `strip()` on the individual name elements while iterating from `names_list`. There are 2 Jones' and your implementation does not remove the second one because of the `split()` strategy.

Comment: @samkart thanks for pointing that out, I have incorporated it in the answer.